# What does "Possibly being eaten by Diana" mean? Thanks

Tags: meaning-in-context

I need some explanation of what "Possibly being eaten by Diana" means. Thanks.

My Chinese subtitle explained that Ms. B will have lunch with Diana (Ms. B's lady boss). I'm guessing that probably means Ms. A will not have lunch because Diana has Ms.B buried with work. Ms. B is an assistant and started working just right out of college. [It's conversation from American Drama, younger]

Ms. A : Hey, what are you doing for lunch?

Ms. B: `Possibly being eaten by Diana` (B's lady boss). Why?

Ms. A: I'm supposed to meet Lauren (A's friend), and I could really use your help keeping her entertained while I read this thing.

Ms. B: Sure.

Ms. A: Yes. You're the best.

Diana : Back in an hour. And think about the book!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ms B. is suggesting that because Diana is such a dragon, an invitation *to* lunch with her might actually mean an invitation to *be* lunch rather than an invitation *for* lunch.

Comment: it means exact meaning : being eaten by Diana, right? Thanks.

Comment: @seemunTeh: Yes, but it's meant to be a joke because, obviously, no matter how horrible a boss is, it's highly unlikely she would be a cannibal.

Comment: dnagirl- Hi, can I say that : Ms. B will have lunch with Diana but a joke , being eaten by Diana. Correct me if i'm wrong. Thanks